# A frontend_type for html code in admin config?

Tags: custom-options

my module is for changes frontend design footer with options in admin config. I read the options default for `frontend_types`, like as http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations#frontend_type_types . But i cant find a correct option for insert html code in field for change the area in the image.
[image: Area for changes by html changes in admin]

Yes, the area is comprised of some .phtml files, however I need to insert content in html in some areas by entering the admin option, how should I do this?